# How to display the plots of a for loop horizontally

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

In a simple situation like the one below, can I show the 3 plots **horizontally**, and possibly change things separately, like in a subplot? NOTE: I cannot just get rid of the loop and do it manually: In the real situation I need to do it from inside the loop!

```
x = np.arange(-2 * pi, 2 * pi, pi / 30)
y1 = 1 + np.cos(x)
y2 = -(1 + np.cos(x + pi))
y3 = (1 + np.cos(x)) - (1 + np.cos(x + pi))
row = [y1, y2, y3]
for i in row:
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, i)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified this is in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single figure with multiple subplot generated inside a for-loop, you can use [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html):

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 10), ncols=3, constrained_layout=True)

for i,k in enumerate(row):
    axs[i].plot(x,k)
```

You can also check [GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec) in case you need a more flexible subplot structure. This [page](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) provides some useful examples.

Comment: I am glad to hear that it worked. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.